# Зачастую меняются цвета в vim после использования make из терминала

Tags: linux, linux-mint, vim, makefile

Захожу в `vim` - цвета нормальные. Выхожу, вызываю `make`, происходит компиляция. Сново захожу в `vim` - цвета шрифтов поменялись, сместились к красному. Не понимаю в чем дело.

содержимое `Makefile`:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.5

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/andrej/Public/git/sapper

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/andrej/Public/git/sapper/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target install
install: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install

# Special rule for the target install
install/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/fast

# Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Available install components are: \"Unspecified\""
.PHONY : list_install_components

# Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components/fast: list_install_components

.PHONY : list_install_components/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/local

# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local/fast: install/local

.PHONY : install/local/fast

# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/strip

# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip/fast: install/strip

.PHONY : install/strip/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/andrej/Public/git/sapper/build/CMakeFiles /home/andrej/Public/git/sapper/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/andrej/Public/git/sapper/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named sap

# Build rule for target.
sap: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 sap
.PHONY : sap

# fast build rule for target.
sap/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build
.PHONY : sap/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named sapper

# Build rule for target.
sapper: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 sapper
.PHONY : sapper

# fast build rule for target.
sapper/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sapper.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sapper.dir/build
.PHONY : sapper/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named uninstall

# Build rule for target.
uninstall: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 uninstall
.PHONY : uninstall

# fast build rule for target.
uninstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/build
.PHONY : uninstall/fast

sources/libsap/create_field.o: sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.o

.PHONY : sources/libsap/create_field.o

# target to build an object file
sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.o
.PHONY : sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.o

sources/libsap/create_field.i: sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.i

.PHONY : sources/libsap/create_field.i

# target to preprocess a source file
sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.i
.PHONY : sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.i

sources/libsap/create_field.s: sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.s

.PHONY : sources/libsap/create_field.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.s
.PHONY : sources/libsap/create_field.cpp.s

sources/libsap/deletes.o: sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.o

.PHONY : sources/libsap/deletes.o

# target to build an object file
sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.o
.PHONY : sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.o

sources/libsap/deletes.i: sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.i

.PHONY : sources/libsap/deletes.i

# target to preprocess a source file
sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.i
.PHONY : sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.i

sources/libsap/deletes.s: sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.s

.PHONY : sources/libsap/deletes.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.s
.PHONY : sources/libsap/deletes.cpp.s

sources/libsap/initial.o: sources/libsap/initial.cpp.o

.PHONY : sources/libsap/initial.o

# target to build an object file
sources/libsap/initial.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/initial.cpp.o
.PHONY : sources/libsap/initial.cpp.o

sources/libsap/initial.i: sources/libsap/initial.cpp.i

.PHONY : sources/libsap/initial.i

# target to preprocess a source file
sources/libsap/initial.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/initial.cpp.i
.PHONY : sources/libsap/initial.cpp.i

sources/libsap/initial.s: sources/libsap/initial.cpp.s

.PHONY : sources/libsap/initial.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
sources/libsap/initial.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/initial.cpp.s
.PHONY : sources/libsap/initial.cpp.s

sources/libsap/input_sizes.o: sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.o

.PHONY : sources/libsap/input_sizes.o

# target to build an object file
sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.o
.PHONY : sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.o

sources/libsap/input_sizes.i: sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.i

.PHONY : sources/libsap/input_sizes.i

# target to preprocess a source file
sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.i
.PHONY : sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.i

sources/libsap/input_sizes.s: sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.s

.PHONY : sources/libsap/input_sizes.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sap.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sap.dir/sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.s
.PHONY : sources/libsap/input_sizes.cpp.s

sources/main.o: sources/main.cpp.o

.PHONY : sources/main.o

# target to build an object file
sources/main.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sapper.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sapper.dir/sources/main.cpp.o
.PHONY : sources/main.cpp.o

sources/main.i: sources/main.cpp.i

.PHONY : sources/main.i

# target to preprocess a source file
sources/main.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sapper.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sapper.dir/sources/main.cpp.i
.PHONY : sources/main.cpp.i

sources/main.s: sources/main.cpp.s

.PHONY : sources/main.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
sources/main.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/sapper.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sapper.dir/sources/main.cpp.s
.PHONY : sources/main.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... install"
    @echo "... list_install_components"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... sap"
    @echo "... install/local"
    @echo "... sapper"
    @echo "... install/strip"
    @echo "... uninstall"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/create_field.o"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/create_field.i"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/create_field.s"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/deletes.o"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/deletes.i"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/deletes.s"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/initial.o"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/initial.i"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/initial.s"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/input_sizes.o"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/input_sizes.i"
    @echo "... sources/libsap/input_sizes.s"
    @echo "... sources/main.o"
    @echo "... sources/main.i"
    @echo "... sources/main.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Comment: так как содержимое make неизвестно, то сложно предположить, что именно он делает. А он может менять характеристики терминала (например, кол-во цветов, проверяется командой tput colors) или вообще меняет .vimrc... кто его знает

Comment: добавил содержимое `Makefile`

Comment: собственно, что я и ожидал - в терминале меняются цвета (видимо, что бы вывод был "красивым"). Либо переписать makefile (например, просто поудалять вызовы изменения цветов), или вручную сбросить цвета после запуска (команда reset (Но не кнопка:), хотя... она также поможет))

Comment: reset не помогает - просто обновляется терминал, но цвета остаются

Comment: тогда удаляйте строки вида "-E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan"